# Permission denied when trying to set cookie in a firefox web extension on a local file

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to set a new cookie in firefox from a web extension on a page that is a local file (with the file protocol: file:///[...]) and I get the following error:

> Permission denied to set cookie {"domain":"","expirationDate":null,"firstPartyDomain":"","httpOnly":null,"name":"myCookie","path":null,"secure":null,"storeId":null,"url":"file:///E:/folder/mypage.html","value":"myvalue"}

This is the script that I am using to insert the cookie:

```
var newCookie = {
        domain: '',
        name: 'myCookie',
        value: 'myValue',
        path: null,
        secure: null,
        httpOnly: null,
        expirationDate: null,
        storeId: null,
        url: 'file:///E:/folder/mypage.html',
    };

    if (cookie.hostOnly) {
        newCookie.domain = null;
    }
    browser.cookies.set(newCookie).then(function (e) {
        console.log('success!');
    }, function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
```

And those are the permissions configured in the manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs"
],
```

I supposed I must need an extra permission, but I couldn't find anything related to that in the documentation. all_urls should include every protocol.

I am able to create cookies manually in the devTools by using simple code like that
document.cookie = "myCookie=myValue";

And I am also able to inject a cookie in the page by using a content script injected like that
browser.tabs.executeScript({ code: `document.cookie = "${newCookie.name}=${newCookie.value}"` });

But this feels like a hack and I feel like I should be able to use the browser.cookies API for that.

What am I doing wrong here?